# Finding hidden cells using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've been trying to write a script to copy formatting from one workbook to another and, as anyone dealing with openpyxl knows, it's a big script.  I've gotten it to work pretty well, but one thing I can't seem to figure out is how to read from the original if columns are hidden.

Can anyone tell me where to look in a workbook, worksheet, column or cell object to see where hidden columns are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worksheets have `row_dimensions` and `column_dimensions` objects which contain information about particular rows or columns, such as whether they are hidden or not. Column dimensions can also be grouped so you'll need to take that into consideration when looking.

Comment: But 'read_only' mode doesn't have these attributes. Is there any other alternative

Answer (score 9):

The attributes you are looking for are inside the `column_dimensions` and `row_dimensions` attributes of the `Worksheet` object.

These are bound dictionaries whose values are `ColumnDimension`/`RowDimension` objects. The specific attribute you're looking for is `ColumnDimension.hidden`.

The following will print the column letter of all hidden columns in worksheet `ws`:

```
for colLetter,colDimension in ws.column_dimensions.items():
  if colDimension.hidden == True:
     print(colLetter)
```

And for rows:

```
for rowNum,rowDimension in ws.row_dimensions.items():
  if rowDimension.hidden == True:
     print(rowNum)
```

As I understand it, loading your workbook as `read_only` can mess with `ws.row_dimensions`, so be careful in this case.

Comment: Please could you explain what you mean by `read_only` messing with `ws.row_dimensions`? Is there some issue tracker on the package's site explaining this?

Comment: @gofvonx Sorry, no, I don't remember where I read this. I do know that opening in read_only mode causes some attributes to disappear. For example, ws.merged_cells no longer exists as an attribute when opening a file in read_only mode in openpyxl 3.0.4: `AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'merged_cells'`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I encountered an issue with the `row_dimensions` being messed up, but in `read_only=False`, so probably unrelated.

Comment: @otocan is there anything similar to do in read_only mode? read_only mode doesn't have these attributes of `row_dimesnions` or `column_dimensions`