# How to retrieve only visible cells in Excel for Python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlwings

I want to merge only visible cells in Excel, but I failed.

When seeing many posts on Stackoverflow, I know `openpyxl` may help me with `row_dimemsion[].hidden`

It didn't work.

Is there any other ways to retrieve only visible cells?

I want only visible cells because sometimes they need to be filtered or hidden.

Please kindly advise me. It bothers me so long.

```
import os
import glob
import xlwings as xw
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter


xw.App().visible = False
path = os.getcwd()
x=input('name：') + '.xlsx'
target_xls = os.path.join(path,x)
data = []
for file in glob.glob(path+'\*.*'):
    if file.endswith((".xls", ".xlsm", ".xlsx")):

        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
        for sheet in wb.sheets():
            for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
                data.append(sheet.row_values(rownum))
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(target_xls)
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        for i in range(len(data)):
            for j in range(len(data[i])):
                worksheet.write(i, j, data[i][j])
        workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

I want it be:

[image]

Comment: Does this thread help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257353/finding-hidden-cells-using-openpyxl Check out the non-accepted response for code to try.

Comment: can't go. that's exactly the way i've tried before