# Read only visible rows in excel with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, filter

I'd like to read only the visible rows form an excel worksheet in python.

the input (excel sheet):

[image]

so when I filter for example:

[image]

as an output in python , I will get just the visible data (1 row) in this case.

here my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(r'C:\Bureau\test\Data.xlsx') 
ws = wb['workload']

# iterate over all the rows in the sheet
for row in ws: 
    if ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row].hidden == False:
        for cell in row:
            print(cell.value)
```

the code works but it gives results in this format:

[image]

but I want to have with a normal format like a table or dataframe.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean by `visible` rows?

Comment: @  Mayank Porwal I mean by visible rows , that if I do a filter in excel than I will read the data in python , I will have just the visible rows that are not hidden because of the filter.

Comment: @ Mayank Porwal I 've tried this one but it's not giving me the data!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257353/finding-hidden-cells-using-openpyxl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a dataframe from the visible rows you could try something like this.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

wb = load_workbook(r'Data.xlsx') 
ws = wb['workload']
data = []

for row in ws: 
    if ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row].hidden == False:
      row_values = [cell.value for cell in row]
      data.append(row_values)

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

print(df)
```

Comment: yes it's working thank you so much , this is what I want to have as a results!

Comment: @norie Thanks! That was helpful. But could you please explain what is `row_dimensions[row[0].row]`. When I googled, I only got info about `row_dimensions` that it is used to set the height and width of a row. But I didn't understand `row[0].row`. Also when I tried in my code, irrespective of index in row i.e., `row[0]`, it gave me same/correct output. Eg: Even when I tried with `row[3].row`. So, it would be little helpful if you can explain `row[0].row`

Comment: @norie Could you please help me the same issue but when in readonly mode? When I used the solution, it gave me error saying `AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'row_dimensions'`