# How to ignore the hidden rows while reading xlsb file using python script or pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, pyxlsb

I have test.xlsb file in that few rows are hidden.
When I use the pyxlsb lib I can able to skip the empty rows.
Is there any command to find the hidden number of hidden rows.?

```
from pyxlsb  import open_workbook
wb = open_workbook(test.xlsb)
wb_sheet = wb.get_sheet('Test')
wb_sheet.rows(sparse=False)
```

or do we have any pandas command to ignore the hidden rows

```
 excel_df = pd.read_excel(test.xlsb, engine='pyxlsb', sheet_name='Test', skiprows=1,   secols=colum_to_read)
```

Comment: this might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66159583/2375421

Comment: unable to open the .xlsb file using openpyxl lib