# Pandas read excel and flag rows with striketrough

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl, strikethrough

I have to work on an Excel sheet with python so I can later put it in a database.

My problem is, that I have quite a lot of rows/cells with <s>striketrough</s>. I want to read the excel normally and flag every row with one or more striketrough cells. I just found a solution for skipping these rows but I want to flag it.

I did find a way to print the strikethrough rows using `openpyxl` but I wanted to use pandas because I have to add and cut a lot of columns later on and pandas is best for that.

Comment: Pandas doesn't read Excel files itself. It uses openpyxl to read only the data, not the styling. It doesn't even skip hidden rows. You'll have to use openpyxl to read, inspect the cells and add the rows you want to a Dataframe. [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155870/read-only-visible-rows-in-excel-with-python) may help

Comment: This may be of interest: https://www.heurekadevs.com/a-brief-look-at-cpython-string

Comment: thank you, do you know if I can add a column filled with 0 using openpyxl and in every row containing a strikethrough it adds 1 to the belonging cell of the new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to imagine how looks like your *spreadsheet* but here is an example to give you the general logic. Basically, we use [`Font.strikethrough`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.fonts.html?highlight=strike#openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font.strikethrough) from [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl) to check if a the font of a cell is striked or not.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

ws = load_workbook("file.xlsx")["Sheet1"]

data = [[cell for cell in row] for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

df["Flag"] = [
    any(cell.font.strikethrough for cell in row) for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2)
]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  col1  col2   col3   Flag
0  foo     1  test1   True
1  bar     2  test2  False
2  qux     3  test3   True
3  baz     4  test4  False
```

*Input used :*

[image]

Comment: thats great, i just have the problem, that my df has 1025 columns instead of just 19. i think it also loads all empty columns

Comment: I tried cutting the empty ones but then it cuts all columns without a name and i cannot rename them either

Comment: Can you show how looks like your spreadsheet ?

Comment: It's working now, I wrote *data = [[cell for cell in row] for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2,max_col=19,values_only=True)]* and then *df[´Flag]=[any(cell.font.strikethrough for cell in row) for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=len(df))]* . So I just set the size and it´s working now

Comment: But do you have an idea for flagging the row when it has a backroundcolor? I tried with *cell.fill.start_color.index* but I can only get it for a specific cell and not for the whole df.

Comment: In the spreadsheet I made above, you can use `any(cell.fill.start_color.index == "FFFFFF00" for cell in row)` or `any(cell.fill.fgColor.rgb == "FFFFFF00" for cell in row)` to flag the cells with a yellow color for example.